# Compiled MVC Views Still Render Slowly On First Request

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 5.x app which has had its views precompiled and merged into a single assembly. Even after all this the first request to a view after AppDomain startup is slow, it does not matter which view is requested as they are all slow the first time the view is requested. Digging in with MiniProfiler I can see it is the "Render" time on the view which takes the majority of the time and upon additional requests to the view the Render time is reduced by about 90%. So to be clear it is this first-time Render that is taking allot of the time. I was not expecting to see this bit of slowness due to the fact all of views have been precompiled and I do not believe it is the JIT that is causing this massive slow down...anyone have any guesses or insights?

Please note, this is not the very first request of a web application, this is the first request of a particular view/page. For example, for the test below the app had been running for hours and was taking requests constantly but the test captured the first request for this view.

First Request

[image: Capture of MiniProfiler]

Second Request

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC ASP.Net startup time revisited](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794580/mvc-asp-net-startup-time-revisited)

Comment: Alas, I don't know if this has any answer. The first time an ASP.NET MVC web application starts up, it usually takes about 5 seconds. Pre-compiling the views doesn't seem to have any effect. I've never seen a real answer to this by Microsoft.

Comment: @RowanFreeman This is not the first request of an AppDomain/web app but the first request of a particular view/page. I have made this more clear in the question.

Comment: Nope. Actually was about to test again with latest build od mvc 5x, don't think it has been fixed however.

Comment: I encounter this as well, and I'm using a "hello world" MVC 5 application.

Comment: Same here: Though I noticed that the slowdown of this first request of a page is not there when "run without debugging" is chosen.

Comment: What do you mean by run without debugging? -- do you mean turning off Emit debug information in the precompile settings?

Comment: Remove any reference to Entity Framework and try again, to ensure this is not affected by Entity Framework warm up time.

Comment: We are not using Entity framework and have no references to it.

Comment: Hi @ToddCarter, did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: @lisburnite no unfortunately not - I have moved on to dot net core and have not revisited this one. I did rule out any perf issues with view lookups.

Answer (score 0):

Strange! In order to be 100% sure what exactly happens, however, I'd do the following:

1. I'll redirect the run-time compilation (yes, there'll be one since at 
   least Global.asax needs to be compiled) like this:

   ```
   <system.web>
       <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" tempDirectory="c:\temp\asp.net" />
       ...
   </system.web>
   ```
2. I'll investigate the contents of the folder before and after the
   first run. Maybe it'd be even better to have a copy of the original.

From your description of the problem it seems like everything should be just fine and there would be no differences between the runs. Still comparing contents of the folder before and after may reveal some difference.

Another cause might be some caching but I can guess you have already sorted this up.

Comment: There should be no runtime compilation here - our MVC app is precompiled and is not updatable and as a result there is no global.asax since it is compiled as well. I will however give your test a try and take a look. The other line of investigation is to see if different compilation options (Debug vs release vs PDB, etc) plays a role here.

Comment: Let's recall what this issue is: first run is much slower than any of the following ones, right? If so, the reasons are either in some preparation before the first run, that is compilation, or preparations for faster second, third, etc. runs, say caching. I wouldn't expect that type of build, debug or release, would affect this.

Comment: And also, maybe you'd want to pay attention at IL code JIT compilation. Although very fast, it happens at least once, that is before a piece of code is first time invoked. Still, such a big difference, and during the render phase is (despite whether it is "pure" render, or render + something else) is quite unlikely to be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the exact same issue for months: It happened to me in some views only.

Apparently, the rendering of the views is not that straightforward as I thought, since MVC needs to run a couple of operations to determine the exact .cshtml to use for an action, its partial views if you have any, etc etc.

What did the job for me is to use **[Razor Generator](https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator)** which **processes Razor files at design time instead of runtime**. (if you wanna give it a shot, I suggest first trying it with a view you know takes time to load at first attempt).

From the website:

> One reason to do this is to avoid any runtime hit when your site
>   starts, since there is nothing left to compile at runtime. This can be
>   significant in sites with many views.

The downside of implementing the **Razor Generator** is that you no longer need the .cshtml files: so if you want to change a view, you have to recompile the project. But that's not an issue necessarily, at least not for me.

Install the Razor Generator from the VS extension gallery first (like it's explained on the website) and then the nuget package.

Trust me: you are gonna be so relieved you're gonna cry ☺

Comment: So what does Razor Generator do that the built in aspnet view compilation and merging not do to make this work? Have you tried to use the built in design time complication tools?

Comment: RazorGenerator allows processing Razor files at design time instead of runtime, allowing them to be built into an assembly for simpler reuse and distribution.
There's a confusion regarding "compilation": when you set `<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>`, you're actually telling the compiler to just check for errors in the view: the difference is that RazorGenerator includes a .cs class per each view (or only the views you want) as part of the compiled assembly: so basically you're saving the work of MVC to interpret each view the first time.
Which compilation tool are you referring to?

Comment: We are building the views via a publish profile that is setup to build all views into a single assembly in release mode. The view files are deployed but are just marker files which was generated by the pre-complication tooling. A single assembly which we named Web.Site.Pages.dll is 5MB in size and using Reflector you can see all the compiled view classes within the ASP namespace. This assembly is placed in the bin directory along with a *.compiled file for each view. That said, how does RazorGenerator differ here?

Comment: Ok, I get it now. The only thing I see different between your environment and mine is that the compiled code of the views is compiled into the same assembly of the web project. I don't have any .compile file, tough; that's another difference I see. 
[This](http://i.imgur.com/JLp9sor.png) is how my project in VS looks like.
Another difference altough I don't know how different is from your build logic is that the generated .cs files use some Generator Types (check their description in the RazorGenerator link) that might be simplifying the job. I'd give it a shot, but of course it's your call☺